# Is there a way to lock the focus point on the Nikon D5500?

Tags: nikon, focus-point-selection

Is there a way to lock the focus point on the Nikon D5500? On other models there is a dedicated "L" switch but I can't find a similar function on the D5500. As a workaround I have to hit OK after each shot in order to move the focus point back to center.

Comment: In which mode are you shooting? In the "Point and Shoot" modes (mode dial on "Auto" or crossed flash symbols) the focus points are chosen automatically by the camera.

Comment: I've tried all modes. after I switch to single-point focus, the location changes as I move the camera.

Comment: @RussellZ " the location changes as I move the camera ". maybe you have kept your focus mode as auto-continuous which makes the cam to follow the previously focused point.

Comment: Nope, tried all focus settings and the point still moves.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot lock the focus point on the D5500. It does not have a focus-lock lever like the D7000 series models do, nor does it have that option in the menu. (It's one of the many little reasons Nikon gives you to buy the more expensive cameras.) Pressing OK after every shot seems like a rather imperfect substitute because sometimes you want to select a point that's off-centre, and you would lose it that way.

However, you can possibly mitigate the problem of accidental movement of the focus point somewhat. The part of the touch-screen display closer to the buttons is called "touch Fn" in Nikon parlance, and sliding your finger over it when the display is off can perform various functions. One of them is moving the focus point, and I believe this is the default setting. I find that I often inadvertently move the focus point around with my nose when that's enabled. If you have the same problem, go to the **Custom Settings** menu, section **f: Controls**, and select **f3: Assign touch Fn** to assign a different function or turn the "touch Fn" feature off. The downside is that you lose that feature this way, which is rather useful. And of course it won't save you from accidentally moving the focus point with the multi selector.

Answer (score 0):

There is an AF-L button on the back of the camera. There also is a way oflocking the Auto Focus in the menu. Get into your menu and scroll down to where you see a pencil, and scroll to where you see Assign AE-L/AF-l. Use the multi selector to choose assigning AF-L for lock only.

Comment: That locks the focus but not the focus point (the location of the box on the focus grid).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the manual for this camera, it seems that "Single-point AF" is only available in Close up, Candlelight and Food scene modes and Silhouette, High Key and Low Key effects modes. I'm looking at page 75 of the US English PDF.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer.
When you use live view, just above the left corner is all the focus points you can select. Its a sub screen with 3 rows going across by 11 points, and 3 columns interesting in the middle by 5 down, which by not double counting the centre give 39 points.using the arrows around the OK button, move the single point as required, then press OK.